# How to fix a delay in updating xaxis using R's playwith package

Tags: r, interactive, xts, zooming

I am using R's playwith package to interactively plot large chunks of time-series data. As a result, I often zoom in and zoom out considerably, to the point where a single 'by' argument to axis.POSIXct becomes impracticable (i.e., sometimes I want to look at the whole range of the data, thus preferring by="year", while some other times I zoom in for detail and then a by="day" would be much more helpful).

I have devised a way to adjust 'by' and 'format' as a function of the current zoom level, however my solution still imposes a "delay". This delay means that:

1. I select a zoom area with the 'navigate' tool
2. the plot refreshes, reflecting my 'zoom in' action, except...
3. the xaxis remains formatted as if using the previous 'by' and 'format' arguments
4. I now use again the 'navigate' tool to select a zoom area similar to the current plot area (i.e., I don't zoom in at all)
5. The plot area remains roughly the same (as expected) but xaxis assumes the format I expected in 3. (this is the 'delay')

You can check that yourselves using the following code:

```
library(xts)
library(playwith)

xts1 <- xts(rnorm(200, 0), seq(as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), as.POSIXct(100000000, origin="1970-01-01"), length=200))
xts2 <- xts(rnorm(200, 0), seq(as.POSIXct(0, origin="1970-01-01"), as.POSIXct(100000000, origin="1970-01-01"), length=200))

XRANGE <- diff(range(as.numeric(index(xts1))))/3600/24/365

# plot with playwith
playwith(
{
  plot(xts1, xlab="",xaxt="n",ylab="", main="'Zoomable' xlim", ylim=range(c(xts1, xts2)), xlim=range(index(xts1)), type="n", cex.lab=0.7, cex.axis=0.7)
  # choose the appropriate xaxis "by" parameter
  axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(range(index(xts1))[1], range(index(xts1))[2], by=BY), format=FORMAT, las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
  # plot data
  lines(xts1, col="red")
  lines(xts2, col="blue")
},

update.actions=function(playState)
{
  .GlobalEnv$XRANGE <- diff(as.numeric(rawXLim(playState)))/3600/24/365;
  # evaluate the "by" and "format" parameters for the xaxis
  .GlobalEnv$BY <- ifelse(XRANGE >= 2.5, "year", ifelse(XRANGE >= 0.15 & XRANGE < 2.5, "month", "day"));
  .GlobalEnv$FORMAT <- ifelse(XRANGE >= 2.5, "%Y", ifelse(XRANGE >= 0.15 & XRANGE < 2.5, "%Y-%m", "%Y-%m-%d"));
  print(diff(as.numeric(rawXLim(playState)))/3600/24/365);
  print(BY)
},

time.mode=T)
```

Can anyone help me with this? Given my very superficial knowledge on using the playwith package I wouldn't be surprised if I was just using things in the wrong order, not updating relevant variables before they get used in the plot. I have, however, exhausted my ability to fiddle with these very "theoretical" playwith constructs, which I hardly understand.

P.S., the script includes 2 print lines that will show you that the 'by' argument does change when it's thresholds are crossed; it just somehow doesn't get reflected in the plot's x-axis...

Cheers